# How to improve PostgreSQL storage efficiency for storing many repeated strings?

Tags: postgresql, optimization, storage

Peruse this:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
    id      bigserial,
    timestamp   timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    "a text column" text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO test ("a text column") VALUES ('This is a text.');
INSERT INTO test ("a text column") VALUES ('This is a text.');
INSERT INTO test ("a text column") VALUES ('This is a text.');
```

PostgreSQL seems to store 'This is a text.' three separate times, instead of once with internal, automatic references for the repeated ones. This means that my table grows ENORMOUS in just a few hours, even though it only saves the same few strings, over and over... I naturally want it to only store each string only once, and frankly, I still somehow expect this every time and am surprised when it doesn't.

I *could* with my existing knowledge do this (and have, many times):

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
    id      bigserial,
    timestamp   timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    helperid    bigint,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE "test helper"
(
    id      bigserial,
    "a text column" text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (helperid) REFERENCES test (id)
);
```

However, I will now need to write a stupid check before I INSERT each record to make sure it's not already in the "test helper" table. Basically, I can get it to work, but it's a lot of work, annoying, exhausting, and I get another stupid table that clogs up the namespace and generally looks ugly in my list of tables.

This feels like such a common problem, almost as common as the very nice `bigserial` mechanism, so why is there no such feature for this? Or is there? Can I do something like this?

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
    id      bigserial,
    timestamp   timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    "a text column" smartstoragetext NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Oftentimes, one table will have multiple text columns which have a lot of repeated/common values. Making one "helper table" for each such column just feels stupid. It really cannot be "how you do this"...

Simply making the text column an index won't help, unless I've completely misunderstood what an index is. Maybe a special *kind* of index? As long as it's built-in, I'm all ears.

Comment: Does PgSQL support a “column store”? If so, does it offer compression? That would be one approach in MSSQL, as opposed to the traditional method of ‘normalizing the database, each and every time in such cases of large duplicated strings’.

Comment: In either case, this would fall under “compression” - which is an implementation detail, not related to the modeling. The (common/correct?) RA modeling approach is to use another table, as noted.

Comment: @Thirumal Because the whole point is that they are very much *not* unique?

Comment: @user2864740: this is usually known as de-duplication rather then compression. Postgres supports compression (but only for longer strings), but not de-duplication.

Comment: @user13908603 Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: BTW: your FOREIGN KEY is in reversed direction.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I’m suppose I’m spoiled by MSSQL and page compression (which also includes deduplication? via lookup table of values in the page). Granted such still requires leaking implementation details, like using a clustered index to take good advantage of such and defer indexes (or AKs) to what may make better logical keys.. I’ve achieved storages  reductions to ~20% the original on some more duplicate-ish data stores..

Comment: https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2014/04/03/columnar-store-for-analytics/ (cstore_fdw) or https://www.postgresql.eu/events/pgconfeu2019/sessions/session/2738/slides/233/ZedStore-PGConfeu2019-Milan.pdf  (ZedStore) may be worth looking into, depending on usages and limitations. Column stores can benefit significantly from compression of duplicate data in a column. The more duplicate data, the higher the potential compression.